# Another regex issue with space caracters detection at end of pattern

Tags: regex

My regex is :

```
(\w|-|\.)+@((\w|-|)+[.]?(\w|-)+)+[.](\w){2,3}
```

(regex email)

It does find a match for :

> before blabla@blablabli.com after

If I try to add a space character detection at the end of the regex:

```
(\w|-|\.)+@((\w|-|)+[.]?(\w|-)+)+[.](\w){2,3}\s
```

It does not recognize the match anymore.

Why that??

I tested on https://regex101.com.

Comment: `/(\w|-|\.)+@((\w|-|)+[.]?(\w|-)+)+[.](\w){2,3}\s/.test('before blabla@blablabli.com after')` is true.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, your pattern  with `\s` at the end [works](https://regex101.com/r/gq560O/1) for the provided string.

Comment: Why does it find no match on https://regex101.com then?
This site never failed me so far with quite a lot of tests in past months.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a link to your failing test case on _Regex 101_?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qhNzof/1

It finds no match.
If you remove one of the 2 consecutive . at the end of the first line, then it finds a match.
Is this normal???????

Comment: Have you seen the "catastrophic backtracing" error message?

Comment: Yes, what does it mean??????

Comment: It's well explained when the followw the link provided (right panel on te page). Here is the link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: Thx for the hint. ;)
Why does adding \s after  (\w){2,3}   make it "catastrophic backtracking"?
\w cannot be a \s so there should be no backtrack?????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one is indeed much optimized for email detection:

```
\s\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}\s
```

fast and furious.

Answer (score 1):

It fails due to catastrophic backtracking. Your regex is overly complicated. Switch to something like

```
([\w.-]+)@([\w-]*\.?[\w-]+)+[.](\w){2,3}
```

And it will works like a char. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9qq81I/1)

Answer (score -1):

You Can have Multiple Whitespaces after this expression.

^(\w|-|.)+@((\w|-|)+[.]?(\w|-)+)+.{2,3}\s+$

or

(\w|-|.)+@((\w|-|)+[.]?(\w|-)+)+.{2,3}\s+